# Multiple commands produce

Tags: swift, xcode

I just created a new project, and installed some pods. When I try to build, I get these two errors:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Multiple commands produce '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-eobcppugxuuucmefyvotwbqadppx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Demo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.stringsdata':
1) Target 'Demo' (project 'Demo') has compile command for Swift source files
2) Target 'Demo' (project 'Demo') has compile command for Swift source files


Showing Recent Issues
Multiple commands produce '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-eobcppugxuuucmefyvotwbqadppx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Demo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SceneDelegate.stringsdata':
1) Target 'Demo' (project 'Demo') has compile command for Swift source files
2) Target 'Demo' (project 'Demo') has compile command for Swift source files
```

Answer (score 14):

Turns out I had duplicate swift files in `targets` -> `Build Phases` Deleted the ones that where duplicates, and all ok

Comment: Xcode is crazy sometimes, I just added a file using Xcode and this happened. Non sense bug and waste of time.

Comment: Why is this even a problem in Xcode? Having same filename for multiple files is a common scenario, its even in different directories.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same **problem** but in my case, I have **same name** for two **swift files**. The solution for that is **Go to** **Targets** -> **Build Phases** -> **Compile Sources**, and check whether you have the *same named* **Swift** files, and remove any one from there.

Another issue of this error is under **Targets** -> **Build Phases** -> **Copy Bundle Resources**, if there are same named bundled resources, remove any one from that.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a view from an app extension, which was named the same as a view from my main app. Renaming the view from the extension solved the issue.

Comment: Thank's brother. I am just make same class name 2 times

Answer (score 0):

In my case its happening because I'm created a file Constants.swift in Xcode IDE, and how I understand its start intersection with other project files, so check it out, maybe u use some system-names, but where to find it idk.